# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; Trying to GRANT INSERT privilege in mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb, privileges

I am in a mysql terminal and I created a user.

```
CREATE USER 'webuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'identifier';
```

I tried to grant the user privileges with

```
GRANT INSERT ON *.* TO 'webuser'@'localhost';
```

And got the error:

```
Access denied for user 'eligooch'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

So I tried

```
sudo GRANT INSERT ON *.* TO 'webuser'@'localhost';
```

And got

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'sudo GRANT INSERT ON *.* TO 'webuser'@'localhost'' at line 1
```

So I am trying to grant privileges to a user but I am stuck.

Comment: `sudo` is a shell command, not a SQL command.

Comment: You need to connect to the database using the database `root` user, not the Unix root user.

Comment: `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: As @Barmar mentioned `sudo` it's a Linux/Unix command that allows you to elevate your current user account to have root privileges temporarily. In `MySQL` you have to use `root` user or another user if it has grants access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sudo mariadb -u root mysql -e "DROP USER 'webuser'@'localhost';"
$ sudo mariadb -u root mysql -e "CREATE USER 'webuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password123#%';"
$ sudo mariadb -u root mysql -e "GRANT INSERT ON *.* TO 'webuser'@'localhost';"
$ sudo mariadb -u root mysql -e "SELECT host, user, Select_priv, Insert_priv  FROM mysql.user;"
+-----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| host      | user    | Select_priv | Insert_priv |
+-----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| localhost | root    | Y           | Y           |
| localhost | halley  | Y           | Y           |
| localhost | webuser | N           | Y           |
+-----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

Make sure the password used for the user complies with the password policy